# change culture programmatically at runtime (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

How do I programmatically change (override) the current culture (set in web.config) ?
sounds simple but tried different code for hours without any result.  Let start with this : 
option 1

```
   @Html.ActionLink("French", "SetFrenchCulture", "Culture")
      @Html.ActionLink("English", "SetEnglishCulture", "Culture")
...
      public class CultureController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult SetEnglishCulture()
            {
                HttpContext.Session["culture"] = "en-US";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            public ActionResult SetFrenchCulture()
            {
                HttpContext.Session["culture"] = "fr-FR";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Option 2

```
  public void SetLanguage(string lang)
        {
            try
            {

                var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(lang);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureInfo.Name);
                HttpCookie langCookie = new HttpCookie("culture", lang);
                langCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(langCookie);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
```

Switching with web.config works perfectly.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here :

https://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/

works pefectly!!  culture in mvc is extremely particular.